# Which messageBundle does FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getMessageBundle() return?

Tags: java, jsf

When there are 3 message bundles within faces-config.xml, which of these are returned and can I control which one should be returned? When I print out the value of FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getMessageBundle() it returns one of the 3, but can I assure that always the same bundle is returned?

(I ask because I had some strange behaviour somewhere else according to missing key properties, but I don't want to go more into deep for now because it's out of scope of this question)

Comment: Downvoter explain your downvote.

Comment: I upvoted to balance out :) @Bevor

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the facecontext when you are inside a bean:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String messageBundleName = facesContext.getApplication().getMessageBundle();
```

And from there you specify the bundle name:

```
Locale locale = facesContext.getViewRoot().getLocale();
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(messageBundleName, locale);
```

In your faces-config.xml:

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>myBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>de.laliluna.tutorial.messageresource.bean.MyBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

The bundle gets returned by the `<managed-bean-name>` and locale comes from your location.

Also on the jsp:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="path to bundle" var="msg"/>
```

Comment: That's what I do, but how does JSF deside which of all message bundles to return when there are more than one message bundle in faces-config?

Comment: @Bevor I'll add to the answer. :)

Comment: Yes, but can I be sure that always the same bundle is loading and how does JSF decide which bundle to load? I got some missing key property problems which could base on loading a different message bundle. And with this solution, I can't control which bundle to load.

Comment: Ok, loadBundle would answer the question (I upvote it for that) but if there isn't anything else in faces-config than the application tag containing 3 message-bundles and if I don't use loadBundle, which one of the 3 is taken? (This is a company app and I can't change much in basic configuration since it would result in retesting the whole app)

Comment: I believe that would fall into locale then. @Bevor